# Keep every n-th bits and collapse them in the least significant bits

Tags: bit-manipulation

I have a 32 bits integer that I treat as a bitfield. I'm interested in the value of the bits with an index of the form 3n where n range from 0 to 6 (every third bit between 0 and 18) I'm not interested in the bits with index in the form 3n+1 or 3n+2.

I can easily use the bitwise AND operator to keep the bits i'm interested in and set all the others bits to zero.

I would also need to "pack" the bits I'm interested in in the 7 least significant bits positions. So the bit at position 0 stay at 0, but the bit at position 3 is moved to position 1, the bit at position 6 moves to position 2 and so on.

I would like to do this in an efficient way, ideally without using a loop. Is there a combinations of operations I could apply to an integer to achieve this?

Since we're only talking about integer arithmetics here, I don't think the programming language I plan to use is of importance. But if you need to know :

> I'm gonna use JavaScript.

Comment: Why are you against using a loop?

Comment: @gotnull I'm against loop for performance reasons. This code will be executed millions of times in a monte carlo simulation and it needs to be as fast as possible.

Comment: Valid point. So, what have you tried so far?

Comment: @gotnull I'm still at the pen and paper stage, trying to think about a data structure that will allow a fast simulation. For now I have two untested solution, but if I can't find a way to "pack" these bit efficiently one of theses solutions (my otherwise prefered one) is probably not good enough.

Comment: Also it's an interesting problem I think. I like to study and find clever hacks like this.

Comment: What about if you could move them down to bits 0-7, but in the wrong order? Could you adjust for the jumbled order elsewhere in your code without a performance penalty? e.g. b = a & 299593; c = (b | (b >> 8) | (b >> 13)) & 127;

Comment: @samgak I'm gonna use the result to access a lookup table, so the order of the bits is not really important. As long as it's always the same, the lookup table can be built according to this ordering. If you post your solution as an answer I'll accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the order of the bits is not important, they can be packed into bits 0-6 like this:

```
function packbits(a)
{
    // mask out the bits we're not interested in:
    var b = a & 299593; // 1001001001001001001 in binary
    // pack into the lower 7 bits:
    return (b | (b >> 8) | (b >> 13)) & 127;
}
```

If the initial bit ordering is like this:

```
bit 31                         bit 0
xxxxxxxxxxxxxGxxFxxExxDxxCxxBxxA
```

Then the packed ordering is like this:

```
bit 7  bit 0
0CGEBFDA
```